# Unable to login with more than 2 users even with 50 RDS CALs installed

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2019

**Scenario:** We have a WS2019 workgroup server that has RD Licensing and RD Session Host roles installed.

[image: RDS roles installed]

We have 50 licenses installed and License diagnoser doesn't show any problems, all green.

[image: RD licensing diagnoser]

Since this is workgroup server, we have converted our Per User CALs to Per Device CALs using the RD Licensing Manager console.[image: RD License Manager showing installed licenses]

We have set the Local Group Policy to use 'localhost' as License server and License type as 'Per device'.
[image: group policy RD license server setting] [image: group policy RD licensing mode]

**Problem:** When we try to connect to the server with more than 2 users, we get a pop-up asking to disconnect one of the existing sessions.

[image: Issue connecting with more than 2 users]

I have tried reinstalling the licenses, removing and reinstalling the roles but no use. I don't know what else to do.

Comment: I have also checked the following registry key and it is set to 2 (as it is expected for Per Device licenses): `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\RCM\Licensing Core\LicensingMode`

Comment: This is in the wrong place. StackOverflow is for programming questions only.

Comment: Okay. Didn't know it. Should I delete this?

Comment: This probably belongs better into https://serverfault.com if you want to move it

Comment: Please move it to the correct forum if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dumbest solution I could ever imagine.

We were using the `.rdp` file downloaded from the Azure portal. This RDP file had the predefined parameter `administrative session:i:1`, that means it was starting the session as administrator. This was causing the issue. I don't know if this is the default behavior or a bug in RDP but I kept hitting the wall because of this.

Started a new RDP session with normal **RUN > mstsc** and it worked without any problems. Now, I can login with more than 2 users without any problems.